# Problema con concurrencia de monitores en Java [SOLUCIONADO]

Tags: java

soy un estudiante de la UPM y tengo un problema con un código en lenguaje Java, el proyecto ya está hecho solo pretendo que alguien me hecho una mano a identificar por que mi código no funciona correctamente y si alguien pudiera darme algún consejo para mejorar el código.
Se trata de un programa en que simula el cajero de un banco, como funciones tiene que realizar:

1. Ingresar dinero: que ingresa el dinero en la cuenta dada y si la cuenta no existe la crea con ese dinero.
2. Transferir dinero: que recibe dos cuentas y el valor a transferir, si las dos cuentas son iguales salta excepción y si alguna de las dos cuentas no existe o la cuenta origen no tiene dinero suficiente para realizar la transferencia el proceso se bloquea. Si cumple los requisitos la transferencia se realiza de forma normal.
3. Disponible: que muestra el dinero que tiene una cuenta en concreto y salta excepción si la cuenta no existe.
4. Alerta: recibe una cuenta y un valor, si la cuenta tiene igual o mas dinero que el valor especificado el proceso se bloquea si la cuenta tiene menos dinero del especificado salta una alerta.

La base de cuentas inicial es 0 y se van creando cada vez que se realiza "ingresar", las cuentas pueden ser infinitas y los procesos se realizan también de forma infinita.
A continuación adjunto el código que he realizado yo hasta el momento:

```
package cc.banco;

import es.upm.babel.cclib.Monitor;
import es.upm.babel.cclib.Monitor.Cond;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import es.upm.aedlib.map.*;

public class BancoMonitor implements Banco {

    //Declaracion de variables.
    private Monitor mutex; //Monitor.
    private HashMap<String, Integer> listaCuentas; //Almacena las cuentas que existen en el banco y su contenido.
    private HashMap<String, Integer> colaAlertar;   //Almacena los datos de los bloqueos de alertar.
    private HashMap<String, Monitor.Cond> condAlertar; //Almacena las conditions de alertar.
    private HashMap<ParesCuentas, Integer> colaTransferir;  //Almacena los datos de bloqueo de transferir.
    private HashMap<String, Monitor.Cond> condTransferir; //Almacena las conditions de transferir.
    public BancoMonitor() { 
        //Inicializacion de variables.
        mutex = new Monitor(); 
        listaCuentas = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        colaAlertar = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        condAlertar = new HashMap<String, Monitor.Cond>();
        colaTransferir = new HashMap<ParesCuentas, Integer>();
        condTransferir = new HashMap<String, Monitor.Cond>();
    }

    
    public class ParesCuentas{
        private String cuenta1; //Cuenta origen de la transferencia.
        private String cuenta2; //Cuenta destino de la transferencia.
        public ParesCuentas(String cuenta1, String cuenta2) {
            this.cuenta1 = cuenta1;
            this.cuenta2 = cuenta2;
        }
        //Devuelve el identificador de la cuenta origen.
        public String getCuenta1() {
            return cuenta1;
        }
        //Devuelve el identificador de la cuenta destino.
        public String getCuenta2() {
            return cuenta2;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Un cajero pide que se ingrese una determinado valor v a una
     * cuenta c. Si la cuenta no existe, se crea.
     * @param c nÃºmero de cuenta
     * @param v valor a ingresar
     */
//-----------------------------------------INGRESAR-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void ingresar(String c, int v) {
        //Zona critica
        mutex.enter();
        //Si la cuenta ya existe sumamos el valor a ingresar al contenido que ya tenia la cuenta.
        if(!listaCuentas.containsKey(c)) {
            listaCuentas.put(c, v);
        }
        //Si la cuenta no existia.
        else {
            listaCuentas.replace(c, listaCuentas.get(c), listaCuentas.get(c) + v);
        }
        desbloqueo();
        //Salimos de la seccion critica.
        mutex.leave();
    }//Fin ingresar.

    /**
     * Un ordenante pide que se transfiera un determinado valor v desde
     * una cuenta o a otra cuenta d.
     * @param o nÃºmero de cuenta origen
     * @param d nÃºmero de cuenta destino
     * @param v valor a transferir
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException si o y d son las mismas cuentas
     *
     */
//-----------------------------------------TRANSFERIR---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void transferir(String o, String d, int v) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        
        //Comprobamos que las dos cuentas no sean la misma.
        if(o.equals(d)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        //Si son cuentas distintas.
        else {
            //Entramos en seccion critica.
            mutex.enter();
            //Comprobamos que existen las dos cuentas y si no bloqueamos y si hay dinero suficiente.
            if(!listaCuentas.containsKey(o) || !listaCuentas.containsKey(d) || listaCuentas.get(o) < v){
                //Añadimos los datos a la cola.
                colaTransferir.put(new ParesCuentas(o, d), v);
                //Añadimos la condition a la cuenta.
                condTransferir.put(o, mutex.newCond());
                //Bloqueamos.
                condTransferir.get(o).await();
            }
            //Realizamos la transferencia.
            //Restamos el valor a la cuenta origen.
            listaCuentas.replace(o, listaCuentas.get(o), listaCuentas.get(o) - v);
            //Sumamos el valor a la cuenta destino.
            listaCuentas.replace(d, listaCuentas.get(d), listaCuentas.get(d) + v);
        }
        //Se produce desbloqueo si se dan las condiciones
        desbloqueo();
        //Salimos de la seccion critica.
        mutex.leave();
    }//Fin transferir

    /**
     * Un consultor pide el saldo disponible de una cuenta c.
     * @param c nÃºmero de la cuenta
     * @return saldo disponible en la cuenta id
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException si la cuenta c no existe
     */
//----------------------------------------------------DISPONIBLE----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public int disponible(String c) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        int saldoDisponible;
        //Comprobamos que la cuenta ya existe, si no existe lanzamos una alerta.
        if(!listaCuentas.containsKey(c)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        //Si si que existe realizamos la operacion.
        else {
            //Entramos en seccion critica.
            mutex.enter();
            //Tomamos el saldo de la cuenta.
            saldoDisponible = listaCuentas.get(c);
            //Llamamos a desbloquear
            desbloqueo();
            //Salimos de la seccion critica.
            mutex.leave();
            //Devolvemos el saldo de la cuenta.
            return saldoDisponible;
        }
    }//Fin disponible

    /**
     * Un avisador establece una alerta para la cuenta c. La operaciÃ³n
     * termina cuando el saldo de la cuenta c baja por debajo de m.
     * @param c nÃºmero de la cuenta
     * @param m saldo mÃ­nimo
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException si la cuenta c no existe
     */
//--------------------------------------------------ALERTAR---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void alertar(String c, int m) throws IllegalArgumentException{ 
        //Comprobamos que la cuenta existe y si no lanzamos una excepcion.
        if(!listaCuentas.containsKey(c)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        //Si la cuenta si que existe.
        else {
            //Seccion critica.
            mutex.enter();
            //Si la cuenta no tiene el valor por debajo de m bloqueamos.
            if(listaCuentas.get(c) >= m) {
                //Añadimos la cuenta y el limite a la cola.
                colaAlertar.put(c, m);
                //Añadimos la cuenta y una condition asociada a ella a la lista.
                condAlertar.put(c, mutex.newCond());
                //Bloqueamos.
                condAlertar.get(c).await();
            }
            //Llamamos a desbloquear.
            desbloqueo();
            //Salimos de la seccion critica.
            mutex.leave();
        }     
    }//Fin alertar

    public void desbloqueo() {
        boolean desbloqueado = false;
        Iterator<String> it = colaAlertar.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext() && !desbloqueado){
            String clave = it.next();
            //Si el contenido de la cuenta es menro que el punto minimo de alerta desbloqueamos la funcion.
            if(condAlertar.containsKey(clave) && condAlertar.get(clave).waiting() > 0 && listaCuentas.get(clave) < colaAlertar.get(clave)) {
                desbloqueado = true;
                //Desbloqueamos.
                condAlertar.get(clave).signal();
                //Borramos de la lista la condition.
                condAlertar.remove(clave);
                //Borramos de la cola los datos.0
                colaAlertar.remove(clave);
            }
        }
        Iterator<ParesCuentas> it2 = colaTransferir.keySet().iterator();
        while(it2.hasNext() && !desbloqueado){
            ParesCuentas clave = it2.next();
            //Si existen las dos cuentas y la cuenta origen tiene dinero suficiente desbloqueamos.
            if(condTransferir.containsKey(clave) && condTransferir.get(clave).waiting() > 0 && listaCuentas.containsKey(clave.getCuenta1()) 
                    && listaCuentas.containsKey(clave.getCuenta2()) &&
                    listaCuentas.get(clave.getCuenta1()) >= colaTransferir.get(clave)) {
                desbloqueado = true;
                //Desbloqueamos.
                condTransferir.get(clave.getCuenta1()).signal();
                //Eliminamos la condition.
                condTransferir.remove(clave.getCuenta1());
                //Eliminamos los datos de la cola.
                colaTransferir.remove(clave);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda, también son bienvenidos consejos acerca de limpieza de código y buenos hábitos de programación.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno voy a comenzar a escribir todo lo que vi al tratar de interpretar el código, quizás me equivoque pero al fin a cabo no puedo ejecutarlo.

Falta encapsulamiento en la clase `ParesCuentas` en las variables `cuenta1, cuenta2`, has creado sus getters pero no agregaste `private` estas variables.

Metodo `ingresar(String c, int v)`:
Hay una variable `int contenidoCuenta;` que no se esta utilizando.

Metodo `transferir(String o, String d, int v)`:

- Hay un comentario confuso y que no explica realmente lo que pasa en las condiciones if:

> Comprobamos que existen las dos cuentas y si no bloqueamos y si hay dinero suficiente.

Sin embargo estas comprobando que las cuentas no existan y si no tenes dinero.

El comentario deberia ser algo mas explicativo a la situacion, como por ejemplo:

> Comprobamos si las cuentas no existen y si no hay dienro suficiente,
> en ese caso bloqueamos la cuenta de origen.

Luego procedes a bloquear la cuenta de origen dentro de ese mismo if, pero
que cuenta estas bloqueando si no existe?

```
//Bloqueamos.
condTransferir.get(o).await();
```

Si dentro de las condiciones estas comprobando que no existan.
Como entonces bloqueas transferencia entre la cuenta de origen?, esta nunca se realizara, la cuenta no existe. Eso no lo entendí, pero saliendo de ese mismo (if) heces lo siguiente:

```
//Realizamos la transferencia.
//Restamos el valor a la cuenta origen.
listaCuentas.replace(o, listaCuentas.get(o), listaCuentas.get(o) - v);
//Sumamos el valor a la cuenta destino.
listaCuentas.replace(d, listaCuentas.get(d), listaCuentas.get(d) + v);
```

Aca hay un problema creo, esto debería estar dentro de un `else`, de el `if` anterior, siguiendo el flujo de ejecucion,
estarias:

**1**- Comprobando que las cuentas no existan o si la cuenta no tiene dinero suficiente, entonces las bloqueamos.

**2**- Transferir, sin importar si las cuentas existen o no.

No deberías poder transferir dinero a una cuenta que no exista, debe estar dentro de un `else`, ya que mas abajo
saliendo del (else-principal), usas el método `desbloquear();` y  `mutex.leave();` para salir de la sección critica, lo digo para
no poner un `return` que sale del método.

Metodo `desbloqueo()`:

Hay un solo `boolean desbloqueado = false;` para dos interadores que se activan cuando este este en `false` uno después del otro,
el problema esta que el primero lo agrega a `true`, para salir del bucle, si necesitas que el segundo interador se active una vez
el bucle `while` del primero halla finalizado, debes agregar la variable devuelta a `false`, ya que la comparten.

```
Interador 1
while(it.hasNext() && !desbloqueado){
    ...
}

desbloqueado = false;

Interador 2
while(it.hasNext() && !desbloqueado){
    ...
}
```

Si necesitas que se active el segundo, solo si el primero no puede asignar la variable a `true`, mejor, antes de crear el interador
pregunta si la variable esta en `false`, si esta en `true` entonces retorna.

También según lo que vayas a hacer, lo mejor seria remplazar los interadores por simples bucle `foreach` utilizando `entryset`,
son los que mas uso ya que a la hora de revisar el código creo que se entiende mas, de hecho según esta discusión: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962459/java-collections-keyset-vs-entryset-in-map
es mucho mas eficiente usar estos antes de los interadores con `keySet()`. puede usar los `Entry<K,V> ... : hash.entrySet()`, `keySet()`, `values()`
para lo que quiera hacer, si así lo desea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407378/entryset-vs-keyset-in-java-collection/44407448

Y quizás acortar las condiciones `if` dentro del `while` con un operador ternario `boolean (...) ? true : false`, para hacer mas legible el código,
o mi monitor es bastante chico como para ver todas esas codiciones `if` en la pantalla, por lo menos en el segundo `while` que tiene muchas condiciones.

A eso no lo puede probar, y tampoco remplazar por un `for` el `while`, por falta de las librerías y de clases, quizás me equivoque al
interpretar como funciona pero en fin no puedo ejecutar el código para darme mas cuenta de como esta.

Pero creo que esos detalles,
son los únicos que he encontrado que se pueden cambiar o mejorar.

Suerte con tu proyecto, e ignora los de los comentarios, si te parece cambiarlos bien, si no bien, eso es a tu gusto, era solo para arrancar jaja, me gustaría saber también eso de que estas bloqueando una cuenta que no existe según la lógica que vi...

Comment: Antes de nada muchísimas gracias por tus comentarios, voy a realizar muchos de los cambios que me has aconsejado. En cuanto al await que comentas que bloquea una cuenta que no existe, lo que pretendo es realizar un map "condTranseferir" donde como key guardo el id de la cuenta origen que pretende realizar la transferencia y como value una condition del monitor que es la que bloqueo en ese momento y que en la función "desbloqueo()"  solo desbloqueo si existen la cuenta origen y la cuenta destino y si la cuenta origen tiene dinero suficiente para realizar la transferencia.

Comment: En cuanto al tema del if y el else despues de las condiciones de bloqueo si no tengo mal entendido diria que el await sale del proceso y "ejecuta" un mutex.leave() y por lo tanto no sería necesario el else, pero lo revisaré por si acaso lo he entendido mal.

Comment: `.await();`  hace return  y leave(); en otro método? esto no para la ejecución que viene después, si es así no llegaría a cumplirse el final del else donde agregaste `desbloqueo();` y `mutex.leave();`, estos deben ir al final del else pero dentro de el, ya que haces un `mutex.enter();` al comenzar, has la salida dentro también, o simplemente quita esos métodos ya que dijiste que `.await();` hace un `leave` no hay necesidad entonces de que estén ahí.

Comment: Cierto, voy a meter  las llamadas a esas funciones dentro del else, muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo acabo de cambiar y de ajustar todo y aparentemente funciona de forma correcta. Muchísimas gracias por tus comentarios y tus consejos.